# App is taking so long to load on simulator.

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode5.1

I am trying to run this app on Xcode 5.1 on the simulator and it has been over 2 hours and it still hasn't loaded. I restarted my computer and still nothing. Any ideas on how I could fix this? I would post a pic of the top of the page loading but I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Was the app stopped at a breakpoint?

Comment: Ok if the app has run and its taking over 2 hours to load... its not running... have you tried using breakpoints?

Comment: it stuck at? if breakpoint not available try log the error

Comment: Does it not show up at all on the simulator? Or does it appear to hang once the app opens? If it opens and then just hangs, its probably a breakpoint.

Comment: Are you doing some network calls when the App is Launching or in the View that your are loading at launch? If yes, comment out the network call and see. But as for the Simulator, it gives an "Failed to Load, SpringBoard error". Are you not getting this ??

Comment: Try resetting the simulator. iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...